# Windows mobile and Bluetooth programming SDK to download

Tags: c++, bluetooth, mfc, windows-mobile, zebra-printers

I am writing a program that is to run on a `Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5` terminal.
The program is written in `C++ with the MFCs`.
The terminal has to connect to a `Bluetooth` `Zebra` printer to send it `ZPL` files.
For Windows Mobile developments I am using `MS Visual Studio 2005`.
The PC's OS itself is `Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit`.

I would like to use the libraries `ws2_32.lib` and `irprops.lib`
and the headers `winsock2.h`, `ws2bth.h` and `BluetoothAPIs.h`.

I read that all these are available as part of the `Windows SDK`.

**My problem is that I don't know which SDK to download (I would need a download link here).**

Can you help me?

********************EDIT 1**

With `MS Visual Studio 2005` and the `Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5 DTK` I get some build errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BtMob, Configuration: Debug Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Professional DTK (ARMV4I) ------
1>Compiling...
1>stdafx.cpp
1>D:\programs\ms_visual_studio_2005\VC\ce\atlmfc\include\afxv_w32.h(38) : fatal error C1189: #error :  MFC requires WINVER to be #defined to 0x0400 or greater
```

Can you help with that issue?

**********************EDIT 2**

If I create a new project and build it right afterwards, I get the following error messages:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: BtMob4, Configuration: Debug Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Professional DTK (ARMV4I) ------
1>Deleting intermediate and output files for project 'BtMob4', configuration 'Debug|Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Professional DTK (ARMV4I)'
1>Compiling...
1>stdafx.cpp
1>_CE_ACTIVEX was not defined because this Windows CE SDK does not have DCOM.
1> _CE_ACTIVEX could be caused to be defined by defining _CE_ALLOW_SINGLE_THREADED_OBJECTS_IN_MTA, but it is recommended that this be done only for single-threaded apps.
1>_ATL_NO_HOSTING was defined because _CE_ACTIVEX was not defined.
1>Compiling...
1>BtMob4.cpp
1>MainFrm.cpp
1>BtMob4Doc.cpp
1>BtMob4View.cpp
1>Generating Code...
1>Compiling resources...
1>Linking...
1>corelibc.lib(armsecgs.obj) : fatal error LNK1103: debugging information corrupt; recompile module
```

**********************EDIT 3**

Executing the hotfix `VS80sp1-KB949009-X86-INTL.exe` solves the problem described in EDIT 2.

Answer (score 0):

You need the Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5 DTK: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5389

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Sorry for asking this but, before I could see your answer I installed: `Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8`
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852363). Can you tell me if this SDK would be suitable (for my specific purpose) or not? Thanks.

Comment: I just edited my initial question. I am having a build error. Can you have a look? Thanks

Comment: The EDIT2 build error says that a MS lib is corrupt. There seems to be a fix  at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949009/ (ref: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2857d97d-f8c2-4390-97e0-a1be54348b52/corelibclibarmsecgsobj-fatal-error-lnk1103-debugging-information-corrupt-recompile-module?forum=vssmartdevicesnative)

Comment: using web.archive org I found the file names and a source: http://web.archive.org/web/20140801144549/https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=18623, http://thehotfixshare.net/board/index.php?autocom=downloads&showfile=10051 If you need another file search the internet.